# what is the best way to use sockets with database entries in another file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io, mern

I have used socket in another file, not in server.js/index.js

**socket.js**

```
const io = require('socket.io')()

io.on('connection' , (socket)=>{
  console.log('We are getting a NEW Connected');
  socket.on('sos', (msg)=> {
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('emergency' ,'SEND BY SERVER TO ADMIN');
    // socket.emit('sos1' ,str)
  })

  socket.on('hello' , (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    socket.emit('hello' , "msg from server for admin in hello" );
  })
})
module.exports = io
```

now is it a good idea to emit any data from my controllers, meaning from where I am inserting/updating my database, as I update my database I want to notify my client instances through emitting from a socket to a specific event. How can I do it and is it good to do it in this way?

Comment: Answers are probably opinion-based. I would personally use some sort of message bus (even a simple `EventEmitter`) to decouple the database part from the `socket.io` part.

Comment: Thanks, @robertklep, can plz share a link for this event emitter way to do it properly. And also if there is a standard to do things? can we use the socket anywhere? link in controllers etc.

Comment: There's some explanation and code here: https://dev.to/ivandotv/event-bus-pattern-via-native-eventemmiter-class-72a

Comment: well that was handly thanks bro